# XS engine, 404 on non-HTML files

Tags: hana, hana-xs

Having made a `.xsaccess` file and a `.xsapp` file, I can access my UI5 application on `https://host:8000/app/index.html`. It does however give me 404's on non-HTML files in the same folder and subfolders, for instance my manifest, Component and other JS files. `XSJS` files seem OK.

Am I missing a setting somewhere?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the following code in your .xsaccess and see if it works.

```
{
    "exposed" : true,
    "authentication" : [{"method":"Basic"}], 
    "cache_control" : "no-cache, no-store",
    "cors" : {
        "enabled" : false
    }
}
```